# jQuery slideUp / slideDown not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to create two div's with a header and a content, and when I click the header, the content is supposed to slide up to hide itself.

You can find my code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5hLsbuy/3/).

My HTML :

```
<div id="left-content">
    <div class="news-block">
        <div class="block-head">News membres</div>
        <div class="block-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="news-block">
        <div class="block-head">News premium & VIP</div>
        <div class="block-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('div.news-block').on('click', '.block-head', function(){
        var content = $(this).parent().find('div.block-content');
        if (content.is(':visible'))
            content.slideUp("slow");
        else
            content.slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

I red some posts saying that you can't use slideUp() on tbody for exemple, or on a floating div, but as you can see, my "content" div is not floating, and that's why I don't get why it's not working.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#left-content .news-block .block-content {
    background: #c3c3c3;
    margin-left: 8px;
    height: 50px; 
}
```

Use height instead of min-height css property.

**For more info**:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6618

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/6wyk3ztd/

Comment: Thanks, this was so dumb that I didn't thought about it ^^'

Comment: I quickly read the ticket and it looks it is quite old. However this question is just one year old. What versions of jquery are affected by this bug?

Comment: What about having a div with no height set? It has the height the content consumes...

Answer (score 3):

Here is other solution without changing the CSS :

```
$('div.news-block').on('click', '.block-head', function(){
    var content = $(this).parent().find('div.block-content');
    if (content.is(':visible')){
        content.animate({minHeight: '0px'}, 1000, function(){
            $(this).css('display','none');
        });
    }else{
        $(content).css('display','block');
        content.animate({minHeight: '150px'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll take the CSS solution as min-height was just temporary, but thanks anyway :)